# how to use bean into android project?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I use for javaEE project Spring, and I use bean injection with @Servive annotation.
Now I'm going to make android's projects and I'd like to use the similar structure for my service bean. Is it a way to do it?

i.e.

```
public interface GlobalService {
final static String PACKAGE_ACTIVITY = "net.....activity.";

    /**
    * start an activity only by the activity name
    * the intent is declared inside
    * @param activityName
    * @return True if the activity Start else False
    */
public boolean openActivity(String activityName);
 }
```

then I have a class that implements interface

```
 @Service("GlobalService")
 public class GlobalServiceImpl implements GlobalService{

 public boolean openActivity(String activityName) {
    //some code ....
 }
}
```

finally I declare into my class

```
@Autowired
private GlobalService globalService;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/). It's not only [IoC](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes), but also great threading control tool and has many other features. It helps to write less code and does development more freindly.