# Integrate Android App with existing Spring projects

Tags: java, android, spring

So, I'm developing an Android App, and I would like to use some projects that I already have. Those projects are developed using Spring. In general those projects have services that I need to call in order to interact with a remote DB and they do some business logic.

How can I define those services in the android and use them?
Please note that I can't use Web Services.

Something like defining a xml file:

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.test.MyServiceImpl" />
```

And in the Android java files:

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

Comment: By services you mean Android app component Service?

Comment: No. I mean Spring Services. Or simply Spring Beans. Just need to define it in a XML file and use it on java file. I don't know if it's possible on Android. That's the way I use on web apps

Comment: See [this](http://keyholesoftware.com/2012/01/30/dependency-injection-for-android-development-an-introduction/) tutorial

Comment: @Xstian the tutorial looks good, the framework too. Unfortunately it not allows me to use the logic that I already have developed using spring.

Comment: In your code snippet missing only <context:annotation-config/> to work fine ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps but here is the answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426486/how-to-use-bean-into-android-project). As for me I haven't used ordinary Spring with Android but I would suggest you to look at [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) project.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to run your Spring app on Android? Your options as I see it:

1. Make it a web service (which you can't do, but is really the recommended approach)
2. Run Spring on Android (I see challenges down this road)
3. Try out [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) project which should simplify the challenge of (2)
4. Rewrite your spring business logic into Android code. If it's only a few files, I'd do this

Comment: The problem withe the web-service is that I don't have a hosting for java that I can put the code there
I don't want to rewrite the code either because I want to develop a dektop app too.

I see a lot of problems here..

Comment: Yea, unfortunately spring != android. It sounds like what you want  is a Java library that can be used on desktop and android. In that case, you're probably better off removing the Spring requirement from your library and rewriting it using either plain java or only using Java libraries that are known to work on both desktop and Android. There's no simple fix that I know of

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I would go back and start developing that business logic on a php based web service. That way I can put it on my host.